# mysqld many processes/threads

Tags: mysql, linux, memory

EC2 instance specifications:

```
vCPU : 2
RAM  : 4GB
MYSQL: 8
OS   : Rocky 9
```

my.cnf:

```
performance-schema=0
group_concat_max_len = 50000
connect_timeout=30
innodb_parallel_read_threads=1
innodb_purge_threads=1 
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384
net_buffer_length=65536
slow_query_log = ON
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
event_scheduler=off
disable-log-bin=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/slow-query.log
long_query_time=1
performance-schema=0
temptable_max_mmap=67108864
temptable_max_ram=67108864
table_definition_cache = 1024
tmp_table_size=5000000
```

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` output:

```
Id  User Host       db   Command Time  State Info
867 root localhost  NULL Query   0     init  SHOW PROCESSLIST
868 root localhost  NULL Sleep   0            NULL
```

When I run this command `htop` to check memory and CPU I see this:

[image]

There are 30 processes or threads by `mysqld` only althought there is noone using the website currently.
Only about 1GB RAM is free out of 3.5GB.

Why `mysql` is running such many processes while there are no users? How each of them is using 7% of RAM? The sum of 30 processes only is more than 100%!

**UPDATES while having around 1000 visitors**

`atop` output:[image: atop]

`htop` output:[image: htop]

`SHOW PROCESSLIST` returned the same 2 results.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;` => `984`

output results: https://justpaste.it/degg7

Comment: Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see what queries mysqld is processing.

Comment: I think those are actually just threads of the `mysqld` process, not separate processes. `mysqld` keeps a pool of threads on hand so it can process queries quickly. That's why they all have the same memory use.

Comment: @Barmar I added ``SHOW PROCESSLIST`` output to the question

Comment: Like I said, those are just idle threads waiting for something to do.

Comment: @Barmar So it's reserving 2GB or more waiting for queries to excute?

Comment: The virtual size is 1.3GB, that's mostly indexes that have been cached in memory. Only 256MB is resident in RAM at the moment.

Comment: @Barmar Would I need to upgrade to 8GB RAM then to give it and other processes more space in RAM?

Comment: I don't see why. Is the system swapping a lot?

Comment: @Barmar When I get around 1k visitors who are just viewing the website or 30-40 users who are sending many requests per second the CPU hits more than 90% and the server may go down so I'm investing the causes and trying to optimize the configurations/code or increase the hardware.

Comment: You need to show CPU and memory use when it's busy. Your question shows what it's like when it's not doing anything, which is irrelevant.

Comment: You may find SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; to have additional available information.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please - WHEN you have 30 users active, 
OS, Version? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME OR 30 users active  
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: All the processes listed in HTOP are sleeping, nothing is Running.

Comment: I updated the question when there were around 1000 visitors. I hope this helps. `STATUS;` showed an error with no results for this command.